# How can I create an adaptive layout in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout

A website can be designed to adapt to smaller screen sizes using media queries. For example, three columns on a wide screen, one column on a low-resolution phone.

Is there a similar technique for WPF to adjust the layout based on available screen space or parent control size?

For example, I'd like to have 3 columns displayed horizontally on a large screen, but displayed vertically on smaller screen. Ideally, I'd like to formulate layouts like this: "If this control's width is less than 400 points, rearrange these controls in that way."

How can I create an adaptive design like this in WPF? That is, define different layouts for controls for specific parent control sizes?

Ideally controls should be rearranged instead of duplicated or recreated, to avoid being extremely slow.

Comment: Do you mean using XAML alone, or are you looking for a way to do this in code?

Comment: @Zipper Of course, I'd prefer to do this declaratively in XAML. If it isn't possible right away, I don't mind writing some framework code. But eventually, I want to describe layouts without any procedural code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with [`DataTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) and a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to test if the bound value is greater or less than a parameter.

This will allow you to easily adjust the style setters based on a bound value. For example, you could use

```
<Style x:Key="MyControlStyle">
    <!-- Default Values -->
    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True" 
                     Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyWindow, 
                         Converter={StaticResource IsValueLessThanParameter}, 
                         ConverterParameter=400}">
            <!-- Values to use when Trigger condition is met -->
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In the case where you have a more complex layout with many pieces that change based on some triggered value, you can replace entire Templates with your trigger instead of just individual properties

```
<Style x:Key="MyContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BigTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True" 
                     Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyWindow, 
                         Converter={StaticResource IsValueLessThanParameter}, 
                         ConverterParameter=400}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LittleTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I believe you can also bind to the [`SystemParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx) object to use additional information about the application in your bindings, although I can't remember the exact syntax for it right now.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the UWP flavour of WPF, then you might use [`AdaptiveTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
<AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" MinWindowHeight="900" />
```

Comment: Considering UWP and WPF are mostly unrelated technologies, I'd say "UWP flavor of XAML GUI" or something like this. :) I wonder whether something like this exists for WPF. Maybe subclassing DataTrigger could work.

Comment: Fair enough. They're similar enough that you can be productive in UWP pretty much straight away, learning the bits you can't use along the way. Sometimes you discover new stuff, like I did with `AdaptiveTrigger` today.

Comment: There is an open ticket that could have some more upvotes for the WPF project to bring the required `VisualState.StateTriggers` property to WPF. https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2080

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to do something like this is in code, and you'll need to create a custom layout. The simplest way of doing that is to create a new class that inherits from Panel, and implement MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. I've done custom layouts before, and they can end up being a rather large pain to get working for all cases. If you Google "wpf custom layout" you'll get some good examples to start with. Given all the functionality you want, you'll definitely have your work cut out for you. You'll probably want to look at attached properties to see about putting annotations in the xaml to give your code an idea of what should be included at the different sizes.

Comment: This is actually easily done with `DataTriggers` that change the layout properties or possibly even the `DataTemplate` based on the parent control's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` property. You don't need a custom layout in code for this