# WPF move middle control to next row when width exceeds available space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have 3 UserControls at the top of my window and I want to arrange them accordingly based on available real estate. What I want is to have the 3 controls aligned horizontally when there is space available but I want the centre control to move down to a new row/line when the window is resized. The left and right control should always be aligned horizontally. All 3 controls are fixed width. Example below.

[image]

 <sup>*Wide window with the 3 controls aligned.*</sup>

[image]

<sup>*Smaller window - middle UserControl moved below.*</sup>

I've tried using `WrapPanel` and `DockPanel` but I don't think either of these are what I want. I imagine what I want is somewhere in-between the two.

Is there a good way to do this with any standard WPF controls or is the best solution to extend `Panel` and implement this logic myself?

Comment: ar the controls left and right fixed in size?

Comment: I don't see any built in control doing that,  you'll be writing code.  What happens when the user narrows the window just enough enough that middle won't fit? Won't there be a big gap? Or is this for different sized monitors and the user isn't really resizing the window by dragging?

Comment: @DenisSchaf Yeah, both fixed size.

Comment: @Andy I should have mentioned that my window width minimum is limited to disallow this. The following controls, not in example, are full width and require a minimum width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to achieve the same functionality as you want. Here is the result of my code:

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Width="160" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Left UserControl"/>
        <Button x:Name="MiddleUserControl" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="300" Height="60" Content="Middle UserControl"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="160" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Right UserControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Grid.ColumnDefinitions[1].ActualWidth < MiddleUserControl.ActualWidth + 40)
            {
                Grid.SetRow(MiddleUserControl, 1);
                MiddleUserControl.Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                Grid.SetRow(MiddleUserControl, 0);
                MiddleUserControl.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works fine +1 for that. But it is not MVVM in my opinion...or is it as you only manipulate the view? i would recoomend putting the logic in a converter so it stays conform with MVVM. Btw would like to know how that gif was made :)

Comment: @DenisSchaf Firstly, you record the video using any video recording software. Secondly, you convert your video to gif animation using any online converter.

Answer (score 3):

This is called adaptive layout, and WPF does not have built in controls for supporting that kind of layout.
Though you may get some pleasant results using triggers. Please look at:
[How can I create an adaptive layout in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013959/how-can-i-create-an-adaptive-layout-in-wpf)